# Apalike with \citep

Tags: natbib, apa-style

I'm having trouble with using the `apalike` style together with `natbib`. The point is to have the possibility to use different types of citations (like `\citep`, `\citet` etc. in `natbib`), and at the same time, have my reference list to look just like `apalike`.

Wants:

1. To have brackets and different citations in the text:

   [Stigler, 1950] and Stigler [1950] and Stigler, 1950
2. To display the same citation as in the text on the beginning of each reference in the list. The ideal look of the reference list would be like this:

   [Stigler, 1950] Stigler, G. J. (1950). "Name of article". "*Name of journal*", Vol. "Volume"("number"):"pages"

   Where the `"` marks my input in the `.bib` file.

What I use now:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\begin{document}

\pagebreak
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{References.bib}

\end{document}
```

Once I add

```
\usepackage[square,comma,authoryear]{natbib}
```

In the preamble, I loose the [Stigler, 1950] in the reference list.

And yes, I can do it manually in the text and use `\nocite`, but I have tried to find a better solution for hours without getting anywhere. Open for any solutions (including switching to `biblatex`)!

Comment: Well, since you already mention it, why not using `biblatex-apa`? The full reference you want in point 2 can be easily done with `\fullcite{Stigler:1950}` in this case.

Comment: I tried, but cannot get it to work.

Tried this:
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{References.bib} 

\begin{document}
\cite{Stigler50}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

EDIT: The \fullcite also dont include the brackets in the reference list. It is probably an easy fix, but I don´t know how..

Comment: You can use the solution: `\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}\setunit{\space}}

\begin{document}
\cite{reese,murray,sarfraz} 

\textcite{reese,murray,sarfraz} 

\parencite{reese,murray,sarfraz} 

\printbibliography

\end{document}` However I don't know how to fix the numbers of labelnames in the bibliography.